# Check if administrator user exists in every application run and create if he doesnt exist in Entity Frameowrk 6 / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to be able to check every time the application runs that the admin user exists. If he doesn't i want to be able to create him.

The Identity sample nuget package has a custom dbinitializer like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AfzDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(AfzDbContext context)
    {
        InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    //Create Administrator
    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(AfzDbContext db)
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        const string name = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
        const string password = "xxxxxxxx!";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null)
        {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        var user = userManager.FindByName(name);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name };
            var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name))
        {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But this will run only when the model changes.

Where do i have to put the code in order to do it in every app run?

If i put this in Home/Index i get a null value exception for rolemanager:

```
var db = new AfzDbContext();
ApplicationDbInitializer.InitializeIdentityForEF(db);
```

Comment: Add it inside the Startup.cs class after the ConfigureAuth method calls.

Comment: Define what you mean by "application run".  Do you mean when the app pool is created?  Or do you mean when a user logs in?  Or do you mean every time a page is processed?  Web applications are a bit murky when it comes to this topic.

Comment: Yes you are correct..I think i am closer to the app pool creation. i.e. Every time i hit ctrl+f5 in my VS....

Comment: app pool creation and ctrl-f5 aren't the same thing. Why don't you just do it when the application first starts (`Application_Start`) and never worry about it again?

Comment: @shoe: That sounds right..Please write it as an answer with an example to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something when the application first runs put it into the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs` with the rest of the startup methods

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    //Do Work
}
```

Someone had said to put it into Startup.cs. You could but if you take a look in that file it's really meant for things related to OWIN.